# Remove auto modifier from hotkeys

Tags: autohotkey, modifier

Is there a way to make a hotkey with a modifier that doesn't automatically put the modifier on the output key? ex: `^a::b` -- except, when I hit <kbd>ctrl+a</kbd> it just gives me <kbd>ctrl+b</kbd>, when I just want <kbd>ctrl+a</kbd> to = <kbd>b</kbd>.

Playing a game which for some reason won't let me use hotkey <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + keys so I'm circumventing the issue by setting the hotkeys as something out of the way then setting the actual hotkey I want to those keys in autohotkey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
^a::
Send, b
Send, c
Send, d
Return
```

or

```
^a::Send, bcd
```

Could you show the exact text of line 4 that causes the error?

Comment: how would i type four hotkeys? it gives me the following error: Error at line 4: Line Text: Send, Error: "Send" requires atleast 1 parameter.